# Scroll Модального окна

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Всем привет!
У меня имеется приложение и кнопка при клике на которую появляется модальное окно(в нем содержатся продукты взятые из store(redux)). При открытии модального окна продукты занимают много места(больше чем размер модального окна) и соответственно в окне показывается только часть продукции, остальная часть не отображается.(см. скриншот)
Подскажите пожалуйста способ, каким образом можно сделать скролл модального  окна.  Пробовал через стили, не работает. Может можно сделать через `React.createRef()` через родительский компонент или я ошибаюсь...[image: Modal window].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь как раз вопрос стилей.
модальное окно не скроллится, потому что оно имеет свободную высоту и не ограничена скроллом. установите этому модальному окну фиксированую высоту(например, `height: 100vh` или же ограничение на высоту (`max-height: 100vh`) и у вас появится возможность скролла этого окна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, к сожалению не работает

Comment: у моего окна вот такие стили: 
const MODAL_STYLES = {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: '50px',
    zIndex: 1000
}


const OVERLAY_STYLE = {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)',
    zIndex: 1000
}

Comment: добавьте к моему ответу еще стиль `overflow: scroll` модальному окну

Comment: Дай Бог вам Здоровья!